# ng-repeat items from a javascript object not repeating in the expected order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <div  ng-repeat="mod in pTab">
        {{$index}}{{mod.modelGallery}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The pTab object looks like:

```
pTab{
modelData1={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-2";
    }
modelData2={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-3";
    }
modelData3={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-3";
    }
modelData4={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-3";
    }
modelData5={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-3";
    }
modelData6={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-3";
    }
modelData7={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-3";
    }
modelData8={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData9={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData10={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData11={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData12={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData13={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData14={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData15={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-1";
    }
modelData16={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-4";
    }
modelData17={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-4";
    }
modelData18={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-4";
    }
modelData19={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-4";
    }
modelData20={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-5";
    }
modelData21={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-5";
    }
modelData22={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-6";
    }
modelData23={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-6";
    }
modelData24={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-6";
    }
modelData25={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-6";
    }
modelData26={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-6";
    }
modelData27={
        modelGallery: "Gallery-6";
    }
}
```

I would expect the output on the page to display the following:

```
0Gallery-2
1Gallery-3
2Gallery-3
3Gallery-3
4Gallery-3
5Gallery-3
6Gallery-3
7Gallery-1
8Gallery-1
9Gallery-1
10Gallery-1
11Gallery-1
12Gallery-1
13Gallery-1
14Gallery-1
15Gallery-4
16Gallery-4
17Gallery-4
18Gallery-4
19Gallery-5
20Gallery-5
21Gallery-6
22Gallery-6
23Gallery-6
24Gallery-6
25Gallery-6
26Gallery-6
```

But this is what actually displays:

```
0Gallery-2
1Gallery-1
2Gallery-1
3Gallery-1
4Gallery-1
5Gallery-1
6Gallery-1
7Gallery-4
8Gallery-4
9Gallery-4
10Gallery-4
11Gallery-3
12Gallery-5
13Gallery-5
14Gallery-6
15Gallery-6
16Gallery-6
17Gallery-6
18Gallery-6
19Gallery-6
20Gallery-3
21Gallery-3
22Gallery-3
23Gallery-3
24Gallery-3
25Gallery-1
26Gallery-1
```

Am I wrong to expect these to repeat in the same order as they appear in the javascript object that contains them? How can this be regulated? I searched some questions concerning the groupBy filter, but it didn't seem to be what I needed.

Should I assume that this affect is coming from somewhere else in my code? For example this ng-repeat div is nested within a couple of other repeated divs. I can provide more of the larger javascript object these items are contained in, or more HTML if necessary.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Not very clear what real data looks like, that isn't an array you've shown. Is data an array or object literal? Post valid data sample that is actually being used. Even better would be create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: check pTab - You are right to expect that the order in which they are displayed should be the order in which it is stored in the expression - but check out the `pTab` expression and not the individual `mod` expressions.

Comment: Seems that pTab is object and javascript objects don't have order, use array instead

Answer (score 0):

Well objects in Angular's ng-repeat are ordered by their key, but not in order.
I understand that you need to iterate an object's key/value pairs keeping the order in which the properties were declared.
Create a function that sorts the keys:

JS

```
$scope.notSorted = function(obj){
    if (!obj) {
        return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

HTML

```
      <div ng-repeat="mod in notSorted(data)" ng-init="value = pTab[mod.modelGallery]">
       <pre>
           {{$index}}{{mod.modelGallery}}
       </pre>           
   </div>
```

This code is partially copied from 
http://jsfiddle.net/DnEXC/

Hope that you'll find it useful.